# Big O time complexity for nested j = i + 1 loop

Tags: big-o

Can anyone please let me what would be big O time complexity for the following piece of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

It can't be `O(n^2)` since `j = i + 1` ? Thanks!

Comment: "It can't be O(n^2) since j = i + 1" - this is a *non sequitur*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are `n-1` iterations of the outer loop. On each iteration, the inner loop iterates `n-i-1` times. So in total the inner loop iterates `n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1` times. So the number of times that `do something` executes is equal to the sum of the numbers from 1 to `n-1`. That sum is `n*(n-1)/2`, which is in Theta(n^2) and thus also in O(n^2).

Comment: This link may provide some more helpful information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779055/big-o-notation-does-more-complex-mean-faster-or-slower

Comment: sepp2k, thanks a lot for the explanation. @user814064, thanks for the link, it's really helpful.

Comment: I don't understand why we don't multiply inner sum of iterations with the outer loop. `n*(n*(n-1)/2)`. We do that if j starts with 0 all the time to get n*n

Comment: @sidoshi You can't both multiply and sum like that - in either case. When `j` starts at 0, you get `n + ... + n`, which equals `n*n`. When `j` starts at `i+1`, you get `n-1 + ... + 1`, which equals `n*(n-1)/2`. In either case you can either use the sum or the closed form. You don't multiply the closed form by `n` - if you did that, you'd get `n^3` for the case that `j` starts at 0.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks :)