# does merge sort algorithm solves the sorting problem asymptotically faster than the quick sort algorithm in the worst-case and as n grows?

Tags: c#

I'm little bit  confuse if which algorithm is faster. I know in worst case quicksort O(n^2) and  merger sort is O(nl0gn).

I think that merger is faster since is O(nlogn)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12779175/31819330) shows different big O complexities on a graph. [BigO Cheat Sheet](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/) goes into much greater detail, including data structures and sorting algorithms. Can I close your question as a duplicate of the one I've just linked, or is there something more you're looking for? If so, can you edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: The answer to your title is just “yes”. Can you explain which part you’re confused about?